# Unchecked conversion compiler warning java

Tags: java, generics

I'm getting several compiler warnings about my use of generics in one class and could use some help. I have the following setup:

```
Map<EventType, List<? extends Listener>> map;
```

I have several different event types and for each one I want to keep a list of the corresponding listener type. Listener is an interface and there are several interfaces that extend it.

Later on I add a List to this map like:

```
List<StateListener> list = new LinkedList<StateListener>();
list.add(someStateListener);
map.put(Events.STATE, list);
```

And then I get warnings later on ...

```
List<StateListener> list = map.get(Events.STATE);
```

for unchecked conversion.

I read through some other posts but I didn't really see anything that helped. Thanks any comments

Comment: There are ways of making heterogeneous containers like this.  Typically though, when you feel you need this you should either generalize your code more (i.e. just deal with the `Listener` interface) or use separate containers.  You're not gaining much by throwing different types into the same map unless you're going to deal with all items in the same manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee that the `List` coming from `map.get(Events.STATE)` is a `List<StateListener>` since you declared the map with the value type of `List<? extends Listener>`

You need to cast it, or declare accordingly;

```
List<? extends Listener> list = map.get(Events.STATE);
```

Comment: So even though when I initialize the actual list going into the map as     
    List<StateListener> ...
It doesn't matter?

Comment: @user correct. The compiler doesn't magically know anything that you don't tell it.

Comment: But you could also put any other List that extends Listener into the map - that's why it's an unchecked conversion.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks that makes sense. I guess I thought that when you specify the types of the List that would be it.

Answer (score 2):

Effective Java for the Win:
http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=consider+type+safe+heterogeneous+containers&source=bl&ots=yYDnLlu3P2&sig=Yp3JqYaFwrqHVxAP0OKVVgLAg3Q&hl=en&ei=pdiUTs-1FYTw0gGbqoiJCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false

You would have to use the class StateListener as the key for your map though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that the `List` returned by `map.get()` is a `List<StateListener>`. The compiler can only guarantees that, whatever `map.get()` returns will be a `List<? extends Listener>`.

---

So, either declare the `Map` as a map of `List<Listener>`, and deal with the limitation of not knowing which  specific `Listener` implementation an object that comes out of the map is:

```
Map<EventType, List<Listener>> map;
List<Listener> list = new LinkedList<Listener>();
list.add(someStateListener);
map.put(Events.STATE, list);
// later...
List<Listener> other = map.get(Events.STATE);
```

or be more specific in the declaration, and live with *that* limitation:

```
Map<EventType, List<StateListener>> map;
List<StateListener> list = new LinkedList<StateListener>();
list.add(someStateListener);
map.put(Events.STATE, list);
// later...
List<StateListener> other = map.get(Events.STATE);
```

Comment: I know you didn't copy and paste, and our first sentences are almost identical. Spooky :).

Comment: Yes, I enjoyed seeing that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The problem was that I have several different listeners - I ended up going with MarkPeters comment about just dealing with the separate lists.